# What's the right way to copy a file in another folder?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, directory, copy

I have to copy a certain file to another folder, and this has to happen when I click a button.
Now I have two problems: the file is not copied correctly, and the new folder with the new file is created after one or two minutes.
When i say copied incorrectly, I mean that  -0.364384  becomes  -0.365163223838319.

I'm currently using this script in my button (ps I have three buttons for files named 1.json 2.json and 3.json)

```
private string path = "Assets\\Modelli\\Sinc ";
public void salvaEs1()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path)) { Directory.Delete(path, true); }
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    string fileToCopy = "Assets\\Modelli\\daMedico\\1.json";
    string destinationDirectory = "Assets\\Modelli\\Sinc\\";

    File.Copy(fileToCopy, destinationDirectory + "sinc.json");
}
```

Errors are about some code that I use to read the file. But the problem are the errors in the file, non the ones that come from them

Comment: do you mean that the copied file has some different values from the source ?

Comment: Yes. And I don't think that I use some code to modify it before the copy, but it's 23.31 and my brain is too tired to check all the code.
Do you think that the code I wrotein the question is correct?

Comment: File.Copy doesn't change content. If you have incorrect data in the copy then your source data is wrong.

Comment: Ok I'll check right now. So the code is in the question is correct? So probably the problem is somewhere else.
Bonus question: do I have to use  //  or  \   ?

Comment: You shouldn't reference the Assets folder in this way, as when you make a build the Assets folder doesn't exist. If you're using an Editor script, there are [constant references available](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html).